# Is it something wrong on the week count of review system?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

Today, I complete my [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/) review. It says `today 20, week 160` in my profile pop-up. That means I fully reviewed suggested edit `160 / 20 = 8` consecutive days. That's why I thought it calculates last week count includes the same name day in last week. <sup>*1</sup>

Since today is 23rd June, this count seems to calculated from 16th June but **includes 16th June**.

The [last review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5125604) I did today was on `2014-06-23 07:08:39`

The [last review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5067749) I did on 16th June was on `2014-06-16 07:05:57`

I strongly suspect this calculation uses something like `.AddDays(-7)` method <sup>*2</sup> **but from midnight** or something.

Because if it wasn't, it doesn't count reviews that belongs on 16th June since I complete my suggested reviews on today later than 16th June. That's why it wouldn't calculate 16th June reviews if only uses `.AddDays(-7)`.<sup>*2</sup>

Is my assumption correct? Wouldn't be better if I see `140` instead of `160` as a week count when I made full review a week in any section? <sup>*3</sup>

<sub>*1: Since today is Monday, it count's suggested edit reviews belongs on last Monday also.</sub>
<sub>*2: with FirstDayOfWeek also</sub>
<sub>*3: Except close votes</sub>

Comment: stupid question but how do I see my week review count?

Comment: @OGHaza When you review (let's say a suggested edit) you can see your profile on [review home page](http://stackoverflow.com/review) queue in _suggested edit_ part. If you hover your profile picture, you can see daily, week, month and total suggested edit count.

Comment: Ah indeed! 1000s of reviews under my belt but I've never noticed that, thanks

Comment: I think that this is similar to SE’s use of yesterday, which has been discussed before. Don’t have link just now.